# Introducing a vertical divider for TabLayout tabs, using pager

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am using android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.

I want to set a vertical line separator that separate one tab with an another.

I could not find any property that I can set at Xml or code level.

Please advise.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
    android:theme="@style/ArticlesTabLayout" />
```

Code that attach TabLayout with pager:

```
    TabLayout tabLayout = getTabLayout();

tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Style is:

```
 <style name="ArticlesTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabMaxWidth">@dimen/tab_max_width</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/cba_yellow</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
        <item name="tabPaddingStart">12dp</item>
        <item name="tabPaddingEnd">12dp</item>
        <item name="tabBackground">@color/cba_white</item>
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/ArticleTabTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ArticleTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorSecondary</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
```

- I am also keen to know how I can add custom view?
- Why textAllCaps is not working, it is still showing in Caps.?
- How I can put a vertical divider?

Comment: Any one please advise, how can I add a vertical divider between two tabs for TabLayout/

Comment: Answered in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204184/how-to-set-the-divider-between-tabs-in-tablayout-of-design-support-library